# Ionic crashed after splash screen on iOS version 8

Tags: android, ios, iphone, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am testing my application on an iPhone 5 (iOS version 8), when I type

> ionic run ios -d

it runs, the splash screen is showed then the application shows me a white screen. I assume the app crashed.

In the console, it throws the following error

> 10 $digest() iterations reached

However, this issue does not happen on other iOS phones that are versions 9 and 10. It also does not happen on any android device.

I have tried removing and adding the ios platform. The problem still exists.

The installed platforms are : 
  android 5.2.2 and
  ios 4.1.0

the config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.store.app" version="1.8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Store</name>
  <description>
      Store is the No.1 shopping platform.
    </description>
  <author email="helloStore@gmail.com" href="http://www.demowebsite.com/">
      Store Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
      <string>This app needs access to your Photo Library to include a screenshot with feedback foo.</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
      <string>Allow to scan member's pass</string>
    </config-file>
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57"/>
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114"/>
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40"/>
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80"/>
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50"/>
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100"/>
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60"/>
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180"/>
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72"/>
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144"/>
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76"/>
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152"/>
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167"/>
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29"/>
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58"/>
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87"/>
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640"/>
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750"/>
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242"/>
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208"/>
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048"/>
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024"/>
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536"/>
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768"/>
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640"/>
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
  </platform>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.4"/>
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-custom-config" spec="~3.1.2"/>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.102:8101"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: it loooks like somthing going in  a loop ..check if you named corrctly all your controller in routing ...

Comment: but this problem doesn't happen on Android or any other version of iOS. I checked the routing, it's all alright.

Comment: can you post your config.xml ?

Comment: i posted the config file

Comment: try to remove for a  moment all <splash and <icon tag for ios...and put  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" /> ..give a try and check if still crashing

Comment: thank you, I added <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" /> to my code and it worked !

Comment: when going past my homescreen to the next page, the app crashed. Any ideas on what might be going on ?

Comment: always the same error in console?

Comment: yes, but it doesnt happen on the android or other ios versions

Comment: have you tried to set the minimum ios version targeting?

Comment: thank you so much, I don't really understand why this was happening but setting . the ios version fixed it

Comment: can you rate it if is correct? :-)

Comment: can you post it as an answer instead of a comment, please :)

Comment: you're right .. done  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove for a moment all

`<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />`

and then try to set the `minimum ios version targeting`